# Unable to run MAUI project on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: .net, maui, visual-studio-mac

I have a MAUI project that runs on a Windows Device fine on a windows machine in Visual Studio 2022.

Having great difficulty getting it to communicate with my Mac though, so have pulled the code onto it to troubleshoot.

When I try and run the project, I get these messages.

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized.
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.

I have run `dotnet worload install maui` and `dotnet workload install android` and `dotnet workload install ios` but still get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What .NET version is your MAUI app targeting? I see .NET 7 in here, is that also what it says in your csproj or is that .NET 8? Visual Studio for Mac is set to retire so if you really want to check you might want to try the .NET MAUI VS Code extension and try building it with that.

Comment: I actually worked out that for some reason, whenever I switch targets, its best to restart VS. it seems to rebuild something in the background then which allows it to bypass this issue.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is set to retire, you can try using vscode.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-maui       https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/introvideos-csharp